# Load jpeg image texture with libjpeg from QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, jpeg, libjpeg, qbytearray

Hi I have a QByteArray of a jpeg image which I obtained from a QNetworkReply. I see everywhere jpeg image read from file and decompressed like this,

```
FILE * infile;
......
if ((infile = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) 
{
     fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
     exit(1);
}
jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, 0);
jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
```

Then

```
while (scan lines remain to be read)
      jpeg_read_scanlines(...);
```

But how do I read it from the QByteArray instead of a file/stdio stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
void jpeg_mem_src(j_decompress_ptr cinfo, unsigned char * inbuffer,
              unsigned long insize);
```

instead of `jpeg_stdio_src`

```
 QByteArray qarr;

 jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
 jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, qarr.data(), qarr.size());
 jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
 jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

 /// etc..
```

Comment: I already solved this problem the way you described. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use external jpeg library:

```
QByteArray array;
// read data into array here;

QPixmap image;
image.loadFromData(array);
```

should be enough. Qt will autodetect the image format. Just remember to distribute Qt jpeg plugin if you compile your application dynamically.

Comment: I need to do it through libjpeg for my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: If libjpeg does not support reading from raw data, the simplest way may be to just save QByteArray content to file.

Comment: I think it does. But I dont know how :( Its something like using custom source manager.